# DjangoUnicodeDecodeError during calling form.errors with EmailField

Tags: python, json, django, unicode, django-1.9

I am porting my site to django 1.9 and don't know how to resolve this issue correctly.

In my form I have usual EmailField from django forms. If validation fails, it shoud be message about it (I pass `'form_errors': form.errors}` to context for manipulating).

But in that case django returns

> DjangoUnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in
>   position 0: ordinal not in range(128). You passed in
>    ()

in `django.core.validators` there is a validator for it

```
@deconstructible
class EmailValidator(object):
    message = _('Enter a valid email address.')
    ...
```

If I change message to `message = 'error'` all works fine.

So, question: how can I fix this issue without editing django files?

the problem is in calling form.errors, this error raise even if I want only to print it. (`print form.errors`). Another fields errors (IntegerField, URLField, for example) works fine, this problem is only for EmailField.

in view process looks like that now:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
...

if form.is_valid():
    ...
else:
    return JsonResponse({'form_errors': form.errors})
```

last traceback is:

```
  File "/path/views.py", line 331, in custom_form_post
    response = JsonResponse({'form_errors': form.errors})
  File "/path/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 505, in __init__
    data = json.dumps(data, cls=encoder, **json_dumps_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 250, in dumps
    sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/path/.env/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py", line 581, in __iter__
    v = self[i]
  File "/path/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/utils.py", line 146, in __getitem__
    return list(error)[0]
  File "/path/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/exceptions.py", line 165, in __iter__
    yield force_text(message)
  File "/path/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 88, in force_text
    raise DjangoUnicodeDecodeError(s, *e.args)
DjangoUnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128). You passed in <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x40a6a90c> (<class 'django.utils.functional.__proxy__'>)
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback, your view and template. Note that `form.errors` is already a dictionary - I don't see why you are calling `items()`, then converting the result back to a dictionary.

Comment: ^ updated. and thanx for tip about `form.errors` - overdid there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. The problem is in translations. In this case - Russian localization. 
No idea why translation from "native" django localization files failed. 
But for all who have similar problem:

1. Create (if still not) locale file (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#localization-how-to-create-language-files)
2. Add theese rows to `django.po`:

   `msgid "Enter a valid email address."
   msgstr "Введите правильный адрес электронной почты."` (or another translation you need)
3. Compile (`django-admin compilemessages`)